# Magento add price and color in meta description

Tags: magento, meta

I would like to add product price in meta description of products. I don't write meta desc in product options, magento gets it from product desc. (it's ok to me)

```
$description = $product->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
            } else {
                $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
```

How to make Meta desc looks like that= ProductDesc Color only FinalPrice

?

Comment: Are you want to show in admin or frontend???

Comment: are you want to manage  from admin

Answer (score 0):

Pleas copyfile view.php app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product to app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product
here  find  protected function _prepareLayout()
     find  code and comment this

```
$description = $product->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
            } else {
                $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
            }


And try below       


$Color=$product->getAttributeText('color');
            $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
            $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
            $currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($currentCurrencyCode)->getSymbol();
            $price=$currentCurrencyCode .' '.Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice(),false,true); 
            $metaTmp1=$Color.' only '. $price;
            $strlen=strlen($metaTmp);
            $metaTmp2==Mage::helper('core/stri;ng')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, (255-$strlen-5));
            $meta= $metaTmp2.''.$metaTmp1;
            $headBlock->setDescription( $meta) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did:

> //$headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(),
>   0, 255)); $Color=$product->getAttributeText('color');
>               $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
>               $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
>               $currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($currentCurrencyCode)->getSymbol();
>               $price=$currentCurrencyCode .' '.Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice(),false,true);
>
> ```
>         $metaTmp1=$Color.' only '. $price;
>         $strlen=strlen($metaTmp);
>         $metaTmp2==Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(),
>         0, (255-$strlen-5));
>         $meta= $metaTmp2.''.$metaTmp1;
>         $headBlock->setDescription( $meta) ;                   }
> ```

And in HTML code, in Meta desc I see only f ex " only 123" - so the price only.

No I don't need to manage it from admin.